# A term for glass half wall

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, image-identification

What is this thing called ? Is it just a ‘Glass Half-wall’ or does it have another name? And what if it was outdoors ? [image]

Comment: Some people see the glass half empty, some see it half full, some see the glass half wall. Seriously, though, I guess the main point of this wall is to keep people from walking off of the edge of the upper split level?

Comment: A glass pony wall.

Comment: That moment when you realise this question wasn't about some bizarre variation on "glass half full"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would call it a half-height glass separation or partition.

The pinterest image you showed was found using those keywords

Interestingly enough so was [Pony wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pony_wall) and [Half wall](https://www.hunker.com/12003272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-knee-wall-a-pony-wall)

> A pony wall is a short wall. In different circumstances, it may refer to: a half wall that only extends partway from floor to ceiling, without supporting anything. a stem wall, a concrete wall that extends from the foundation slab to the cripple wall or floor joists.<sub>Wikipedia</sub>

Comment: The very meaning of half-wall is that it looks like a wall. It is solid, may be even decorated the same way as walls. If it is glass, or fine woodwork, or whatever, it is not a wall.

Comment: I disagree. Glass walls are walls. I even had a half wall made of glass bricks

Answer (score 8):

I've seen the following two, though they may be technically wrong:

- Glass Banister
- Glass Balustrade

(British English)

Comment: As an Australian, balustrade was my first thought too, the same as you have on a balcony.

Comment: I don’t think either one of those is technically wrong.

Comment: In my mind, a bannister is the part of the stars. Balustrade is a long expanse of protection from falling off a balcony or inner walkway

Answer (score 5):

I would call it a "wood-framed glass railing".  If it were outdoors, I might call it a "wood-framed glass fence".

If the top edge of the railing/fence were glass (instead of wood), I would just call it a "glass railing".

Comment: But the railing is wood!

Comment: Jasper, whether exterior or interior the name is always "railing". a glass wall or a glass fence is a very different thing. Also, notice that no matter whether it is entirely made of glass or partially it will still be a glass railing and because it has more than one component - it is a system. compare a standalone railing with a railing system composed of several railings. Btw, the top edge is probably the handrail as far as I know.

Comment: A railing is normally only on the side of the stairs.

Comment: @mplungjan No, you are wrong. A railing can be wherever it needs to be. A balcony can have a railing, a border of a pool can have a railing.

Comment: @SovereignSun Yes, but do we include the part underneath, in this case the glass part, in the word "railing"?

Comment: @MrLister The entire component is called a railing. It has both a frame and a handrail, and the panel. All these parts can be made of different materials. Mostly they come in parts that can be joined to form a lengthy railing system.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this is simply a part of the **glass railing system**. Basically, a **glass guardrail**. You can often see these in malls and supermarkets, and in office buildings.

> **My personal thoughts**: *People may mistakenly think it's a half wall or a partition wall but it's not. It doesn't split, separate or divide the room. It doesn't enclose an area within a larger area. Notice that it isn't standalone unlike half walls or partition walls, it is a combination of two guardrails creating a railing system.*

What you see here is just a kind of a glass railing system with the handrail made of wood and with rather wide glass panels. The guardrail on the staircase is also a part of the glass railing system. You can google for "***interior glass railing systems***" and you'll find a lot of examples.

Here are a few examples of such interior glass railing systems:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I agree that this is a better name for what’s in the picture. I’m not sure I’d go so far as to say that _glass half-wall_ would be a “mistake”.

Comment: @J.R. Thank you for your comment. I've edited so that people understand that that paragraph is my personal thought.